# Page displays content from different query?

Tags: pages, wp-query, query, get-posts, content

How can I reset all variables in order to get the actual page content?
I keep getting the last post's content I've called from a news-box I've implemented - but need the actual page's content ..

thanks

Comment: I asnwered your other question about something similar, [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10085/newbie-question-combine-page-posts/10090#10090), incase you missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your news-box isn't using clean methods for pulling posts. I'm guessing that you are not using the [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) function. You're probably creating a new `WP_Query` object from scratch?

Try using `get_posts()`, as it will take care of keeping the original page query clean for you.